# Pronouncing "Tsu" and "R" sound in Japanese

Tags: pronunciation

I've been learning Japanese but I am having trouble with pronouncing a few sounds, including "Tsu" and the R sound.

- When I pronounce "Tsu", do I say Tsk with my teeth together or make a fizzy kind of noise?
- Is it correct when I pronounce "Ra", that I say "Da" when tapping the roof of my mouth? If so, how do I know if it's properly done?

Comment: do you know how to pronounce katsu (chicken katsu)? It's not kat-su but ka-tsu, so try to say it with a pause between the ka and the tsu. Pronouncing the R sound, your tongue slightly tap the roof of your mouth where you would when pronouncing D sound. Look for videos for the pronounciation, then you can know whether your pronounciation is correct or not. You can also use Hinative to record your pronounciation and have a native check on them.

Comment: I know a name that sounds like it but it's a English one. I've tried searching for videos but all they keep saying is "repeat D" or say R with your tongue on the roof of the mouth. Then, you say L swinging to R. There's loads of videos and they're confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I pronounce "Tsu", I say Tsk with my teeth together and the a "u~".

To pronounce "Ra", I say "Dra" but the "d" extremely lightly. It kind of sounds like a Spanish "r", you roll your tongue (very slightly) for 1/4 of a second.

Real footage helps, so it might be a lot more helpful if you look t some Japanese pronunciation videos or even google translate.

I'm a native Japanese speaker, so I hope this helps.